# Why did I get this ADC error when I compiled a keymap using QMK MSYS?

Tags: adc, stm32f1, qmk, qmk-firmware

MSYS result:

```
Compiling: platforms/chibios/drivers/analog.c
platforms/chibios/drivers/analog.c:22:6: error: #error "You need to set HAL_USE_ADC to TRUE in your halconf.h to use the ADC."
   22 | #    error "You need to set HAL_USE_ADC to TRUE in your halconf.h to use the ADC."
      |      ^~~~~
platforms/chibios/drivers/analog.c:26:6: error: #error "You need to set one of the 'xxx_ADC_USE_ADCx' settings to TRUE in your mcuconf.h to use the ADC."
   26 | #    error "You need to set one of the 'xxx_ADC_USE_ADCx' settings to TRUE in your mcuconf.h to use the ADC."
      |      ^~~~~
platforms/chibios/drivers/analog.c:110:8: error: unknown type name 'ADCConfig'
  110 | static ADCConfig   adcCfg = {};
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
platforms/chibios/drivers/analog.c:110:29: error: empty scalar initializer
  110 | static ADCConfig   adcCfg = {};
      |                             ^
platforms/chibios/drivers/analog.c:110:29: note: (near initialization for 'adcCfg')
platforms/chibios/drivers/analog.c:111:8: error: unknown type name 'adcsample_t'
  111 | static adcsample_t sampleBuffer[ADC_NUM_CHANNELS * ADC_BUFFER_DEPTH];
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~
platforms/chibios/drivers/analog.c:117:8: error: unknown type name 'ADCConversionGroup'
  117 | static ADCConversionGroup adcConversionGroup = {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(deleted thousands of errors all related with analog.c)..........

```
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
 [ERRORS]
 |
 |
 |
make[1]: *** [builddefs/common_rules.mk:361: .build/obj_tomer_v1_default/analog.o] Error 1
Make finished with errors
```

I get this error every time, but I didn't use ADC for any purpose.

I have one EC11 encoder in my application. Is it related to ADC?
I use STM32F103RBT6. The encoder is connected to B6 and B7.

How did this issue happen? How can I solve it? Maybe disable it or bypass it?

Comment: Does it work when compiling one of the existing supported keyboards in QMK? Preferably one that is similar to the one you tried.